# Using only an Excel formula, how do I count the number of rows that meet multiple criteria (including a countif)?

Tags: arrays, excel, countif, sumproduct

I have a spreadsheet with 10 columns.  It contains the name of an item, 8 different ratings, and a dollar amount.  If there is not a rating for a specific column, the value is "NR" (for not rated). See attached example.

[image: example table]

I have two metrics I need to calculate:

1. How many items only have one rating?
2. What is the total amount for items with only one rating?

The list can be refreshed, so the number of items can vary.  Also, I want to avoid using adjacent formulas because of the variable length and high probability of additional columns being added.

I have played with SUMPRODUCT, nested COUNTIF(S), and various array formulas, but I cannot seem to get the solution.  Also, I would like to avoid macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In J2:

```
=SUM(--(MMULT(--(B7:I16<>"NR"),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B7:I16)^0))=1))
```

In J4:

```
=SUM((MMULT(--(B7:I16<>"NR"),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B7:I16)^0))=1)*J7:J16)
```

Depending on one's version one may need to confirm this array formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Amazing.  Thanks for the help, Scott!